# How do I use JSDoc on Windows?

Tags: javascript, windows, jsdoc

Forgive me if this is a daft question but I'm utterly baffled as to how I can use JSDoc on Windows. I'm aware of JSDoc-Toolkit but it's a bit out of date and the google code repository recommends to use JSDoc 3 instead. I have downloaded JSDoc from Github and unzipped the jsdoc-master folder onto my local disk but can't find any solid information as to how to use it to parse my files.

Comment: The documentation on the website isn't very clear how to get it installed. I feel you.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can [download it as an npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdoc) for the [Node.js JavaScript runtime environment.](https://nodejs.org/en/)

1. Install [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) which comes with [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/)
2. Open your a command line
3. Install JsDoc by typing the following command

   `npm install -g jsdoc`
4. Run JsDoc / generate documentation. [more info](http://usejsdoc.org/about-commandline.html)

   `jsdoc path/to/file.js`
5. [Configure jsdoc](http://usejsdoc.org/about-configuring-jsdoc.html) (Optional)

Comment: Thanks, the -g option is very useful! Saves having to run it from the .bin folder

Comment: Even so you dont need to run it from the `.bin` folder. npm creates the `node_modules` folder and installs the package in the current working directory unless the `-g` option is passed. So if you are not installing it globally you should `cd path/to/project_root` before you run `npm install`

Comment: Thanks, one last question: when installing globally, where is the jsdoc folder placed (so I can put templates in there)? I have node.js installed on D:\node, and I've checked the `node_modules` subfolder(s) (inc. in npm).

Comment: Actually, my apologies, you are half right. If you didn't install it globally, you either need to `cd` down to the `.bin` folder or add the path to jsdoc to the start of the command - I refuse to be more specific as this is the wrong way to do it. **You should always install jsdoc globablly**.

Comment: I'm pretty sure on windows it puts global node modules in your user folder `C:/Users/<you>/node_modules`

Comment: You are indeed correct! Thank you for your help, everything is now working correctly.

Comment: in windows 10 I am getting "this program is blocked by group policy..." when I try to run jsoc in command prompt (as adminstrator)

Comment: I doubt your network admin has explicitly blocked JSDoc, its probably a higher level restriction on all executables run from a path (or not running from a path) or something. I would suggest trying a bunch of other node tools to see if you get the same error and also trying some other non-node commands like `ping`, `nslookup` or another system command, -  even try some ruby gems or python [whatevers] and see if they are also blocked by group policy. Maybe you could open a question on SuperUser if this doesnt work

Comment: Before running the command to install, I had to run "npm init" to generate the .json file

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 but I don't have a `C:/Users/<you>/node_modules` folder. The only way I found to run jsdoc is `npx jsdoc`.

Comment: You don't need to `cd` into the `.bin` directory. You should be able to type `npx jsdoc` to execute it, or make an npm/yarn script: `yarn doc` that runs the normal jsdoc command.

Answer (score 0):

The installation is not good documented on the [project-page](http://usejsdoc.org/).

It is much better exlained on the [github-page](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know very much about NodeJS/npm ecosystem. However, I did the following steps below and it worked for me (on windows):

1. Downloaded NodeJS zip file and extracted, it made a directory 'node-v16.15.1-win-x64' with node.exe and and npm.cmd inside
2. Executed command 'npm install -g jsdoc', under the 'node_modules' directory under the 'node-v16.15.1-win-x64' it installed the jsdoc (in a folder) and also made the jsdoc.cmd file inside 'node-v16.15.1-win-x64'.
3. This jsdoc.cmd works with the full path but it does not work without the full path
   jsdoc gets installed and is working with the above steps but to access it from any where without giving the full path, I had to set the 'node-v16.15.1-win-x64' on Windows PATH, that works.

I am not sure if question of OP is answered but JSDoc works for me this way.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not saying this is necessarily the best way, but it worked for me:

1. Install [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/)
2. Open a command prompt
3. As a test, create a folder in your root drive (`c:\test`) and go to it (`cd\test`). I guess there was some sort of permission issue as I couldn't get the following steps to work in my desktop folder.
4. Install the JSDoc package: `npm install jsdoc`
5. There should be a folder in `test` called `node_modules`
6. Go to the `.bin` subfolder in `node_modules`
7. There should be a file called `jsdoc.cmd`. Simple use `jsdoc myfile.js` in the command prompt to execute the JSDoc script on your file

Comment: you need to change step 4 to `npm install -g jsdoc` and you dont need to do anything in the `node_modules` folder.